# How to create a Javadoc for a Spring boot application?

Tags: java, documentation-generation

I am working on a spring boot application and trying to create java doc for all the methods and classes I have written for documentation purpose. So I want this java doc to be created on the remote server as well so that it can be shared across.

How should I proceed? Should I create java doc using my IDE and then push to git remote or is there any other way? Please help me with this.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Please take the [tour] (and earn a badge while you are at it) / Also read our [ask] page and [edit] your question to improve it.
Good questions tend to receive quicker, better answers from the community. - BTW, you might want to look into Swagger API docs - it has a nice hook for Spring Boot to generate documentation and make it available online on the same server where the app is running

Comment: Is Swagger [https://swagger.io/] something that can help you?

Comment: Will I be able to create documentation for each method of each class that I have written using swagger?

Comment: I think mainly it will create the API documentation for the endpoints.  If you want every method in every class, is there a reason you are not using the `javadoc` command line utility? https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/javadoc/javadoc-command.htm#JSJAV-GUID-EAAAE17F-E540-42A0-B22B-4D2B2FD3E4D2

Comment: I would love to use javadoc. So to create the javadoc in remote, I need to update my command line arguments of my application right?